# How to access client camera for Face recognition using openCV in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying to build a website using Django, I have a concept of integrating face login for my website and It's perfectly working on the server computer and when I try to access the same from the client computer, the camera pop-ups in server computer rather in the client computer. I couldn't able to understand how I can access the client camera and pass it to my face recognition code?

I have written Django code for face signup using the basic OpenCV concept for face recognition.  And Its perfectly working on the server computer and when I access from the client the camera pop-ups from the server computer.

All I used on my code is a simple signup form and OpenCV for face recognition.

What should I need to pass for the object VideoCapture( ) in order to access the client camera and can anyone suggest me any other possible ways to build a face login module.

Comment: You can not open the camera of a client through Django/Python, since that is the backend (it works only at the server side). You will need some HTML/JavaScript to (ask the browser to) open the camera, and then send images to the server side.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Is that possible to send each and every frame that is captured using javascript to the python? If at all so can you get me some more details on it? Thank you

Comment: I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813696/sending-webrtc-video-stream-to-server-with-django-channels